# When nodeos is syncing the blockchain. Where is the blockchain downloaded in Linux?

Tags: nodeos

Where is the blockchain data stored when syncing with the nodeos command on linux ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/data

Answer (score 1):

Your nodeos data is stored in .local/share/eosio/nodeos/data folder.